# One slicer for 2 tables power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have two tables, first contains all `AreaPath` data module wise,

| WorkItemId | Title | ChangedDate | State | StateChangeDate | AreaPath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27997 | logo in Code Provider Access | 16-03-2021 19:25 | New | 12-03-2021 21:53 | Admin |
| 28339 | Password policy needs to be updated | 12-03-2021 21:54 | New | 12-03-2021 21:54 | power |
| 28464 | Update Names of users names | 12-03-2021 21:54 | New | 12-03-2021 21:54 | Admin |
| 29918 | Add capturing capabilities on the Public Portal | 24-03-2021 17:27 | New | 23-02-2021 21:53 | power |
| 29919 | Refactor the code to make sure that the generated value done in a single location. | 23-02-2021 21:55 | New | 23-02-2021 21:55 | Empower |
| 29943 | Placeholder : "Provider Search Compare" needs to added on the Public Portal | 11-03-2021 17:58 | New | 23-02-2021 22:26 | power |
| 29948 | Add Document upload feature | 23-02-2021 22:51 | New | 23-02-2021 22:51 | power |

And i have 2nd table contains AllIteration,

| AreaPath | IterationPath | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| power | power - Sprint1 | 08-03-2021 00:00 | 13-03-2021 00:00 |
| Empower | power - Sprint 3 | 15-03-2021 00:00 | 20-03-2021 00:00 |
| power | power - Migration | 22-03-2021 00:00 | 27-03-2021 00:00 |
| Admin | power - License | 29-03-2021 00:00 | 03-04-2021 00:00 |

Using above table I have created one line graph and one multirow card in a single page. I added slicer for `AreaPath` to categories wise I can see graphs. But the issue is I can only use slicer for belongs to one graph and table. How we can change value of other graph using slicer?

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables?

Comment: @intruderr there is not any relationship. But 2nd table data is latest date data from all areapath which I want to show in card, so there no chance to create any relationship between both tables.

Comment: So if it the second table is the latest data, that means you should be able to create 1 to many relationship by *AreaPath* and then use that column from the second table to filter all the data.  If that's not the case, let me know. I'll provide you a solution later.

Comment: @intruderr 1st tables just a small snapshot of actual table. I have almost 40-45 columns in which i have created more than 20 column using Dax formula calculation using other tables. So 2nd table contain last row of each areapath (in actual datasource there is module name).  So end output is I draw graph based on first table and in 2nd graph is lasted value of each module to show and in slicer contains all modules which must be connected to or sync with both graph.

Comment: @intruderr do you have any solution on it?

Comment: You can create a relationship between the tables in the Model tab of Power BI Desktop. It sounds like you want to create a many-to-one relationship from table 1 to table 2. You can then use the AreaPath column (either one) in a slicer and it will filter both tables. If you are still looking for a solution, I can answer it more formally below.